# Retire Dataset with Its Relationship Class

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, relationship-class, archiving

I need to retire datasets from our SDE databases to our **Retirement Geodatabase**. There are several relationship classes tied to these datasets. How can I export the feature class with its relationship class intact and working. This needs to be done incase it needs to be un-retired at some point.

[image: Geospatial Data Retirement]

Comment: Would this work: [http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/migrate-relationship-class-tool.htm](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/migrate-relationship-class-tool.htm)

Comment: i like your use of the word retirement

Comment: @gomapping Archiving is overused and really doesn't convey what we are doing. To me something that is archived is on a shelf and is never to be used again unless in dire circumstances. Retirement is just a relocation of data, it can always and easily be pulled out of retirement if needed.

Comment: @OtonabeeGIS I am going to try that tool out now. Will report on its success / failure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well in the end it was super easy. Just copy the **TABLE** to my retired Geodatabase and all of the **feature classes** and **relationship classes** copied as well. Always the easiest answer that is hardest to find.

I just used the ArcCatalog copy and paste functions.